# Jquery - hide div if the cookie exists

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-session

I'm trying to detect mobile devices and give the option to the user to select between the mobile and full site. The issue I had was the modal window pops up every time the page loads (obviously it detects that the device is a mobile in every page load). So what I did was, creating a session and check if the session already exists. For some reason nothing happens on page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
/**
 * jQuery.browser.mobile (http://detectmobilebrowser.com/)
 * jQuery.browser.mobile will be true if the browser is a mobile device
 **/
(function(a){jQuery.browser.mobile=/android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);

var isiPad = /ipad/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
var check_cookie = $.cookie('it_is_mobile');
if (isiPad == true) && (check_cookie == null){
    $('#modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
    animation: 'fade',                   // fade, fadeAndPop, none
    animationspeed: 600,                       // how fast animtions are
    closeonbackgroundclick: false,              // if you click background will modal close?
    dismissmodalclass: 'close'    // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal

});
return false;
$.cookie('cookie_name', 'it_is_mobile');
}else{
$('#modal').hide();
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope it help you...
Add parentheses to **if** condition---

```
if ((isiPad == true) && (check_cookie == null))
```

I haven't a mobile device to test it. but in Chrome  for PC it runs successfully, isiPad returns false and check_cookie returns null. Debug your code in Chrome to see solution.

Comment: Hi Farid, I get an error with chrome.

"Uncaught TypeError: Object function (j,s){return new b.fn.init(j,s)} has no method 'cookie'"

I checked the mobile detection and it works fine. I only get this error when I try to introduce cookies.

Comment: Download JQuery cookie from here **http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie** and use it in your javascript

Comment: after installing **`cookie.js`** file put the way of this file to your javascript as `<script src="cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

Comment: Thanks Farid. I updated the code as you suggested and don't get any more errors. I have inserted the entire script on the home page of the full site. So when the page loads for the first time the #modal appears, but if someone selects the option to visit the full site, the page loads again with the #modal div, which means the session seems to be not working. Basically it keeps on displaying the #modal every time the page is refreshed... its like a loop.

Comment: change the code `var check_cookie = $.cookie('it_is_mobile');` to `var check_cookie = $.cookie('cookie_name');` and try again. if it works accept my answer ;)